# Validate (custom) before adding file

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I would like to make sure if the user is logged-in or not before **anything** is added to the uploader area (thumbnails).

it's easy enough checking stuff on the `validate` event callback, but I can't seem to figure out how to stop the item from being added to the DOM, even if I return `false` in my validation or `submit` events...the item just gets a class of `qq-upload-fail`... but I want to completly do NOTHING if the user isn't logged in...maybe the validation event handler is not the place to put this logic, but where else?

---

My initialization code (jQuery):

```
this.holderElm.fineUploader({
    template: 'qq-simple-thumbnails-template',
    // uploaderType: 'basic',
    request: {
        endpoint: '/image/upload_image/' + this.settings.uploadID
    },
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions : ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
        sizeLimit         : this.settings.sizeLimit,
        itemLimit         : this.settings.itemsLimit
    },
    retry: {
        enableAuto: true
    }
})
.on("validate", this.onValidate.bind(this) )
.on('submit', this.onSubmit.bind(this) )
.on('error', this.onError.bind(this) )
.on('upload', this.onUpload.bind(this) )
.on('complete', this.onComplete.bind(this) )
.on('allComplete', this.onAllComplete.bind(this) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`onSubmit` event](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submit)  -- which called is before the item has been added to the DOM -- and return `false` or a `qq.Promise` that will be rejected to disable the addition of that item to the file list.

```js
var userLoggedIn = true;

// snippet ...    

onSubmit: function(id, name){
    return userLoggedIn;
},
```

or with promises:

```
function isUserLoggedIn(username){
  var promise = new qq.Promise();

  $.get("/api/user/"+username, function(err, data){
      if (err) return promise.failure(err);
      return promise.success(data);
  });

  return promise;
}

// snippet ...  

onSubmit: function(id, name){
    return isUserLoggedIn(username);
},
```

Comment: it doesn't work. other events are also fired even before the `submit` event. returning false from any of them just rejects the file, but it's thumb is still added. Also tried `qq.Promise` but then I read it's not for that. Well..nothing works anyway.

Comment: Returning false in a submit event handler works as Mark has stated in Fine Uploader 4.4.  If you are seeing something else, there is either an issue in your code, or perhaps you have an old version of Fine Uploader that has an issue with the submit event, but that seems unlikely.  Also I'm not sure what you mean when you say "qq.Promise is not for that".  You can certainly return a promise from a submit event handler.

Comment: you can return a promise but there is no point in that I would say, no? in the docs it says the returning false should be suffice. Ok I know now why it didn't work for me..I used it with `.bind()` so `return` didn't really returned a value where it should have. Thanks guys for taking the time to help!

Comment: @vsync `false` absolutely works. [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) are great if you need to perform some sort of asynchronous work (http request for example), and do something with the result. :)

Comment: yeah, I know what they are. my problem was using `bind()`.